# Should I try a rollback before beginning a new transaction?

Tags: mysql, pdo, transactions, rollback

I have a doubt and I can't find a similar question.

In a generic php script like:

```
$pdo->beginTransaction();
//...
//many things to do...
//...
$pdo->commit();
```

Let's say the user stops the page loading or loses connection before the commit is reached. 
Does the transaction remain opened? Do I have to try a rollback before the beginTransaction?

Answer (score 1):

If you are worried about a user dropping connection, you would be better off using `ignore_user_abort`

[ignore_user_abort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php)

That way, regardless of whether a user stops the page loading or any other consequence, the script runs until completion.